# showing image/slug of wordpress categories

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a 2 part question dealing with the 'categories' section of Wordpress.

I am using this code to display the categories in my Wordpress site.

HTML

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'show_option_all' => 'ALL',
    'title_li' => ''
    );
?>

<h3 class="category-list"><?php wp_list_categories($args); ?></h3>
<h2> ... </h2>
```

I want to replace the category Name with an icon/graphic (from Fontawesome, I am using bootstrap framework), and in < h2 > I want to display the slug but I'm not sure how to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

```
    add_shortcode('custom_categories', 'custom_categories_function');

function custom_categories_function() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => FALSE,
        'taxonomy' => 'ads-category',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'show_count' => 1,
        'pad_counts' => 1,
        'hierarchical' => FALSE,
        'parent' => 0,
        'title_li' => '',
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'echo' => 0
    );
    $all_categories = get_categories($args);
    $html = "<ul>";
    foreach ($all_categories as $categories_item) {
        $html .= '<li class="'.$categories_item->slug.'"><img src="'.  $upload_dir['baseurl'].'/ads_cat_icons/'.$categories_item->slug.'.png"> <a href="' . get_term_link($categories_item) . '">' . $categories_item->name . '</a> (' . $categories_item->count . ')';
        $html .= '<ul>';
        $args['parent'] = $categories_item->cat_ID;
        $html .= wp_list_categories($args);
        $html .= '</ul></li>';
    }
    $html .= "</ul>";
    return $html;
}
```